# Is the set of edges a graph a subset of that graph?

Tags: graph-theory, semiring

Let $G=(V, E)$ be a non empty and undirected simple graph with its edge set $E$. Can we say that $E$ is a subset or sub graph of $G$ in any sense i.e., $E\subseteq G$ ? If so, then we can enjoy some interesting results, namely the semiring $P(E)$ is an ideal of the semiring $P(G)$ under usual union $\cup$ and intersection $\cap$ of graphs or sets, where $P(G)$ is the set of all possible sub graphs of $G$ and $P(E)$ being the set of the edges of the corresponding sub graphs in $P(G)$.

Comment: Is $17$ a subset of $(3,17)$? Of course not.

Comment: $G$ is an ordered pair, so by our usual definition it has at most two elements and almost certainly we don't have $E\subseteq G$. Recalling, however, that graphs can have isolated vertices, the graph that includes only vertices of $G$ connected by edges (and all the edges of $G$) is a subgraph.

Comment: @Malice Vidrine Yes, in this sense the corresponding discrete graph of $G$ will be $V, \emptyset $ which is a subset of $G$ or, for bravity $V\subseteq G$. Isn't?

Comment: No. $(V,\varnothing)=\{\{V\},\{V,\varnothing\}\}$ is not a subset of $(V,E)=\{\{V\},\{V,E\}\}$ if $E\neq \varnothing$, because the latter set does not have $\{V,\varnothing\}$ as a member. Subgraphs and subsets are different things. I invite you to try writing out explicitly what you think the "subsets" of the full graph on three vertices should be; perhaps what you come up with will be interesting, but it will almost certainly not be the literal powerset of $G$.

Comment: As an example of why you can't confound subsets and subgraphs, consider the graph with only two vertices and an edge connecting them. How many subgraphs does this have? Five: the empty subgraph, the three non-empty discrete subgraphs, and the total subgraph. However, no powerset has five elements.

Comment: @Malice Vidrine You are right. What i mean by $P(G)$ is not really a power set, but it means a set of all possible sub graphs of $G$. You have clearly explained in the counter example, and in that case $|P(G)|=5$. We know that determining the number of all possible sub graphs in a general graph is a hard problem, but my concern is only on how it forms nice algebraic structures. You please pose your argument as an answer for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **(ordered) pair of sets** $X$ and $Y$ is denoted as $(X,Y)$. In Set Theory a pair of sets is itself a set, usually defined as $(X,Y)=\{\{X\},\{X,Y\}\}$.

However, for practical purposes we generally work with pairs as if they are objects of a different type than sets, mainly to avoid the kind of confusions in your question. Another reason is that there are other representations of pairs different than $\{\{X\},\{X,Y\}\}$ that work equally well. For example $(X,Y)=\{\{\{X\},\varnothing\},\{\{Y\}\}\}$ could be an alternative. It is therefore best not to talk about subsets of pairs of sets.

A **(directed) graph** is a pair of sets $(V,E)$ such that $V$ is a set (of vertices) and $E$ is a set (of edges) such that each edge $e\in E$ is a pair of sets $(v_1,v_2)$ for some distinct vertices $v_1,v_2\in V$. The graph is **undirected** if $(v_1,v_2)\in E$ implies $(v_2,v_1)\in E$.

As a graph is a pair of sets, it does not really make sense to talk about subsets of a graph. Therefore we define the notion of subgraphs: a **subgraph** of $(V,E)$ is defined as a **graph** $(V',E')$ such that $V'\subseteq V$ and $E'\subseteq E$ are subsets, and for each $(v_1,v_2)\in E'$ we have $v_1,v_2\in V'$.

Although a subset of a graph is generally speaking nonsensical, sometimes we *abuse the notation* of subsets to denote subgraphs; for graphs $G=(V,E)$ and $G'=(V',E')$ we could define that $G'\subseteq G$ is a shorthand for *"$G'$ is a subgraph of $G$"*. In fact, this shorthand *only* makes sense if we regard the pair as a different type than a set, since it would otherwise be an ambiguous notation.

In a similar way we could *abuse* notation to define, for example, unions of graphs as $G\cup G'=(V'',E'')$ where $V''=V\cup V'$ and $E''=E\cup E'$. These are technically not really unions, but abbreviations for unions of the underlying sets of the graphs.